# Recursive method conversion until array exhausted

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method in my code that is clunky and isn't scaling.

**y** is an **array** object with key/value like objects, with two properties:

name **string** property to which is unique:
the value is distinguished by the **children** property, which is another array of the same object type as y.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  let objx = y[i];
  let name = objx["name"];
  let inner = objx["children"];

  for (var i = 0; i < inner.length; i++) {
    var z = inner[i]["name"];
    let h = inner[i]["children"];
    console.log(h);
  }

  // more for loops on the h object now, and so on.
}
```

Is it possible to have a method that will just build a new collection that contains all the **name** string property until all respective **children** properties return a 0 count?

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result?

Comment: basic recursion....  make a function and call it.

Comment: To loop through all objects collecting the name property into a new collection until the all the children properties count is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let y = {
  name: 'parent',
  children: [
    {name: 'child1', children: []},
    {
      name: 'child2', children: [
        {name: 'grandChild1', children: []}
      ]
    },
  ]
};

let getNames = y => [y.name, ...y.children.flatMap(getNames)];
let names = getNames(y);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive function.

```js
const
    getNames = array => array.flatMap(({ name, children }) => [name, ...getNames(children)]);
    

var array = [{ name: 'parent', children: [{ name: 'child1', children: [] }, { name: 'child2', children: [{ name: 'grandChild1', children: [] }] }] }];

console.log(getNames(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basic recursion. Make a function that loops over the data and calls itself with the children.

```js
var myData = [{
  name: 'foo',
  children: [{
    name: 'foo-1',
    children: [{
      name: 'foo-1-1'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'foo-2',
    children: [{
      name: 'foo-2-1'
    }]
  }]
}]


function loopOver(array, result) {
  array.forEach( function (data) {
    console.log(data.name)
    result.push(data.name)
    if (data.children) {
      return loopOver(data.children, result)
    }
  })
  return result
}

console.log(loopOver(myData, []))
```